# Open/Launch Various Apps via Voice Commands using STT

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to create an Android App that can listen to various commands and respond to it accordingly. for e.g, if i press mic and say "open whatsapp", it does it.
Question is How do i open Various apps with limited coding?

**following code is to open whatsapp, but if i had to open other various app, Do i need to write same IF Statement for various apps?? wont it be too lenghty?
please provide a better solution.**

```
package example.bot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtSpeechInput;
    private ImageButton btnSpeak;
    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 1234;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
        btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);


        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                promptSpeechInput();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Showing google speech input dialog
     * */
    private void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Receiving speech input
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                    if (result.size() == 0) {

                    } else {
                        String mostLikelyThingHeard = result.get(0);
                        // toUpperCase() used to make string comparison equal
                        if (mostLikelyThingHeard.toUpperCase().equals("OPEN WHATSAPP")) {
                            //informationMenu();
                            txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
                            Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
                            //if (launchIntent != null) {
                            startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
                        } //else if()
                    }

                }

            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    //private void informationMenu() {
    //    Intent intent = new Intent(this, open_app.class);
    //    startActivity(intent);
    //}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Look up design patterns about Command or Strategy pattern. Yes, it will be lengthy. There's no way around converting words into code

Comment: @cricket_007 i didn understand what u mentioned about patterns. can u elaborate?

Comment: [Software Design Patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns).